# Handle multiple query those are exactly same in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have recently 1000 db.collection.find() query and these all are the same queries.

But these query made by different 1000 user so MongoDB has different 1000 query.

so my question is that MongoDB going to process each query individual or MongoDB going to take advantage of the pre-processed query result.

Answer (score 2):

> so my question is that MongoDB going to process each query individual?

Yes. Every query is executed. You can verify this in [mongostat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongostat/#cmdoption-mongostat-humanreadable)

> MongoDB going to take advantage of the pre-processed query result

MongoDB will add the data and indexes that are frequently used to the [working set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#what-is-a-working-set) in memory

It will also cache the most efficient plan for your query as described in its [query planner doc.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/)

Comment: MongoDB takes winning plain from the pre-processed query

Comment: MongoDB uses efficient winning plan for indexes. Yes it run every query every time.

Answer (score 1):

There is document caching on the server side ([documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/#does-mongodb-handle-caching)) so your I/O system is very unlikely to be hit everytime over and over again. Also, the query plan gets cached ([documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/)). That said, the results will not be cached which is also stated in the documentation (first link):

> MongoDB does not cache the query results in order to return the cached results for identical queries.

Comment: so, If we want to first access of query then we need to maintain from our side which will check upcoming query is already fetched or not if fetched then send the result from here otherwise send this query to mongo for fetch record

Comment: Yes, if you want to cache the results you will need to maintain that cache yourself.